# Moving an item programmatically with jQuery sortable while still triggering events

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I am using jQuery Sortable.  I have the HTML setup like so:

```
<ul id='plan'>
  <li class='item'>1</li>
  <li class='item'>2</li>
  <li class='item'>3</li>
  <li class='item'>4</li>
</ul>
```

I want to programmatically move an `<li>` to a different position. I can achieve this with the following JS:

```
$("#plan li:eq(1)").insertAfter($("#plan li:eq(2)"));
```

This works fine except it does not trigger the sortable events like change or update. I have a function which is run on the update event of the sortable but moving the li with JS does not trigger this.

Does anyone know how to trigger the sortable update event?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
$("selector").trigger("sortupdate");
```

you will have to maybe pass in as second argument a function where to put in the event and the ui, event is not as important as ui

the inside code of the sortable widget for event triggering looks like this

```
this._trigger("update", event, this._uiHash(this));
```

So you may want to do following

```
function triggerUpdateFor(selector) {
    var widget = $(selector).sortable("widget");
    if (widget) widget._trigger("update", null, widget._uiHash(widget));
}
```

Comment: Looks like I'm the only one to whom this solution doesn't work. When I try calling the update in this way I get an error saying 'Object has no method _uiHash()'. Help, anyone? I tried various ways to get to the _uiHash but no luck.  I actually need it since I use the ui parameter in my update event handler.

Comment: I had to change this a bit:

- Instead of calling $(selector).sortable("widget") I had to call $(selector).data("ui-sortable"), so that _uiHash was exposed. 

- I also had to set widget.currentItem to be a row element so that my update callback was called with a "ui.item".

Comment: This also did not work for me, neither did what @EddieLoeffen suggested. Ended up using this answer instead: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24484040/295246

Answer (score 9):

### Use the `option` method from the sortable (to retrieve its callbacks)

As each *event callback* is defined as an *option* of the sortable widget it can be retrieved as such by calling the [option method](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-option) for the corresponding *event callback option* (this example uses the `update` callback):

```
$('#plan').sortable({
  update: function(event, ui) {
    // Do something...
  }
});

$('#plan').sortable('option', 'update'); // returns function
```

The update callback [expects two parameters](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-update), the `event` and a `ui object`. The `event` can be set to null and the `ui object` needs to be defined with all the properties your `update callback` expects:

```
$('#plan').sortable('option','update')(
  null,
  {
    item: $('<li>new item</li>').appendTo($('#plan'))
  }
);
```

This works for all event callbacks that you defined (i.e. `receive`, `change` etc.).

[Working JS-Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4mdmF/)

Answer (score 7):

The `trigger` method accepts extra parameters, so if you need the `ui` parameter, you’ll need to pass that in yourself. But you usually just want the target `ui.item`, and in this case, you know what that is:

```
var sortupdate = function (event, ui) {
    // do something with ui.item
};

var $plan = $("#plan");
$plan.sortable({
    update: sortupdate
});
$plan.on("sortupdate", sortupdate); // sortupdate is not automatically bound

var $item = $("#plan li:eq(1)");
$item.insertAfter($("#plan li:eq(2)"));
$plan.trigger("sortupdate", { item : $item });
```

Demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/D7fCz/3/

Answer (score 2):

Even simpler:

```
$('#plan').sortable('refresh');
```