# animate element with index in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I want swap two element in the sortable container with click event, but I cant do this.

http://jsfiddle.net/prince4prodigy/rvfYE/

```
$( "#sortable" ).sortable();
$( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
$('#click').bind('click', function(){
    $('#li-3').animate({index:0},500);
    $('#li-1').animate({index:2},500);
});
```

Comment: [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/#animate-properties-duration-easing-complete) uses CSS properties (`opacity`, `width`, `height`, etc). `Index` is not a property so it does not exist in this case. What are you attempting to do exactly?

Comment: Here's a place to start for swapping them. I'm not sure how to animate the sorting though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911124/moving-an-item-programmatically-with-jquery-sortable-while-still-triggering-even

Comment: @Dom swap element with click  event

Comment: I think he wants to dynamically change the order of the items. For example swap the first li with the third (like you'd do with the mouse)

Comment: There is a mechinism that allow to make multiple drags. You can adapt it to your situation. Onmouseup, add the class `clcked` to the clicked element. If you re-click the same one, remove this class. If you click on another element that doesn't have the `clicked` class, swap the clicked element with `clicked` one

Answer (score 1):

`animate` method doesn't recognize the *index* property, this method mainly has been designed to work with numeric CSS properties and some other specific properties, however you can change the position of the elements using `prepend` and `insertAfter` methods:

```
var $sortable = $("#sortable").sortable();
$sortable.disableSelection();
$('#click').on('click', function () {
    $('#li-1').insertAfter($sortable.children().eq(1));
    $('#li-3').prependTo($sortable);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9uKTY/

An alternative using `slideDown` and `slideUp` methods:

```
$('#click').bind('click', function () {
    $('#li-1').slideUp(400, function () {
        $(this).insertAfter($sortable.children().eq(2)).slideDown(400);
    });
    $('#li-3').slideUp(400, function () {
        $(this).prependTo($sortable).slideDown(400);
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wwh2D/

Comment: ye moshkel kuchik dare, age ghabl az in ke click ro bezani 2 ta <li> yani id:1 va id:3 ro tuye list ja be ja koni dg dorost kar nemikone dar vaghe codi ke shoma neveshti <li> ha ro ja be ja nemikone.

Comment: @SaraGoodarzi En ettfagh vase man nemioyfte, az che mororgari estefade mikonid?

Comment: ba IE va chrome test kardam, har 2 akharin version

Comment: @SaraGoodarzi Besyar khob, man alan ruye Macintosh-am va be IE dastrasi nadaram, baraye man tuye Firefox va Chrome khub kar mikone. fiddle ro test mikonid ya tuye mohite digeE in karo anajm midid? Effecti anjam nemishe va ya Enke effecti vojod dare amma effecte madde nazare shoma nist?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34853/discussion-between-sara-goodarzi-and-undefined)

Answer (score 0):

As I said in comment above :

```
$(function(){
$("li").click(function(){
    //have we clicked on the same item ?
    if($(this).hasClass("clicked")){
        $(this).removeClass("clicked");
     }
    // is there an element that allready have been clicked
     else{
         var firstClicked = $(".clicked");
         //if no, this the first clicked element
         if(typeof firstClicked == undefined){
             $(this).addClass("clicked");
         }
         else{
          swap()....//do your stuff to swapp the elements
         }
});
```

});

Comment: can you complete your answer i'm beginner. thanks.

Comment: try to use insertAfter and insertBefore to move elements in the list. http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/  The documentation says: "If an element selected this way is inserted elsewhere, it will be moved before the target (not cloned)". You 've got all you need to achieve this.