# How to programmatically trigger the update callback of a sortable widget with a button?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

According to this [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ihiQORu/4/edit?js,output) i have a `sortable` list and a button . when click on button something add to `sortable` and i want to know which event of `sortable` is fired?(update,receive) and when finding the event do something on that event.

for example if user click on `add` button i want to know which event is fired and doing something on event . for example if update fire i do some thing in update method of sortable

```
$('.sort').sortable({
 update:function(){
//if update fire do some thing
}
});
  $('#add').click(function(){
  $('.sort').append('<li>Text</li>');
});
```

Comment: As it currently stands, your question is not clear. Try to describe in more detail what is the problem you're facing, and if possible provide an example.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Moving an item programmatically with jQuery sortable while still triggering events](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911124/moving-an-item-programmatically-with-jquery-sortable-while-still-triggering-even)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**The Problem**

When you define the `update` callback as part of the `sortable` widget options, an event called `sortupdate` is *not* bound to the widget. In other words, the callback function defined by the `update` option is indeed called, but an event by that name is *not* triggered in this situation.

**The solution**

If you wish to *trigger* the event manually, you also need to *bind* it manually. Note the event will also be triggered automatically by the widget's regular behavior (e.g. a user sorting the elements in the widget).

For example:

**HTML**

```
<ul class="sort"></ul>
<button id="add">Add</button>
```

**JS**

```
 // Instantiate the widget
$('.sort').sortable();

 // Bind the update event manually
$('.sort').on('sortupdate',function() {console.log('update')});

$('#add').click(function(){
    $('.sort').trigger('sortupdate'); // Trigger the update event manually
});
```

### See [JS Bin Demo](http://jsbin.com/OQOJOca/1/edit)

Comment: @flu answer's below is the better of the two, as it utilizes the official API directly.

Answer (score 17):

### Use the `option` method from the sortable (to retrieve its callbacks)

As the *update callback* is defined as an *option* of the sortable widget it can be retrieved as such by calling the [option method](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-option):

```
$('.sort').sortable('option', 'update');
```

The update callback [expects two parameters](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-update), the `event` and a `ui object`. The `event` can be set to null and the `ui object` needs to be defined with all the properties your `update callback` expects:

```
$('#add').click(function() {
    $('.sort').sortable('option','update')(null, {
        item: $('<li>new item</li>').appendTo($('.sort'))
    });
});
```

[Working JS-Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qup66/3/)

Comment: You can even trigger the function directly by running `$("<selector>").sortable("option", "update")();`