# How to get incrementing serial numbers for new and removed items for jQuery sortable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

With jQuery `sortable` function, I have a simple table, where the entries are sortable. I have figured out how to update the indexing of the entries when they are moved but I'm having issues with adding the new entry. This is the working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Ashonko/xv1foam2/2/).

So far, what I've made to add the incrementing serial index is a mess, so in my example, I've just added `<td class="index">1</td>` in the `append`.

So my questions are:

1. How can I get an incrementing serial no. when is a new item added? And
2. When one item is being removed, the serial is breaking down until I move an item. How can I update the serial number when one item is being removed?

Thanks a lot in advance for your suggestion.

The snippet here is not working for reason I didn't understand, but I added anyway:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   var fixHelperModified = function(e, tr) {
         var $originals = tr.children();
         var $helper = tr.clone();
         $helper.children().each(function(index) {
            $(this).width($originals.eq(index).width())
         });
         return $helper;
      },
      updateIndex = function(e, ui) {
         $('td.index', ui.item.parent()).each(function(i) {
            $(this).html(i + 1);
         });
      };
   $("#sort tbody").sortable({
      helper: fixHelperModified,
      stop: updateIndex
   }).disableSelection();
   $("#addNew").click(function() {
      $('#add').append("<tr><td class='index'>1</td><td>1969</td><td><input name='foo'><button class='delete'>Delete</button></td></tr>");
   });
   $("body").on('click', '#add .delete', function() {
      $(this).closest(".rem").remove();
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<table id="sort" class="grid">
    <button id='addNew'>Add new item</button>
    <thead>
        <tr><th class="index">No.</th><th>Year</th><th>Title</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="add">
        <tr class="rem"><td class="index">1</td><td>1969</td><td><input name="foo"><button class="delete">Delete</button></td></tr>
        <tr class="rem"><td class="index">2</td><td>1952</td><td><input name="bar"><button class="delete">Delete</button></td></tr>
        <tr class="rem"><td class="index">3</td><td>1963</td><td><input name="baz"><button class="delete">Delete</button></td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Fiddle link is very welcome but please also show code in the question.

Comment: Just add `updateIndex` to the add and delete function and you're good to go.

Comment: The snippet here is not working for reason I didn't understand, but added anyway. Thanks @Roamer-1888

Comment: I say decriminalize indices!

Comment: What the hell is decriminalize an index?

Comment: @Ashonko the snipped wasn't working because you tried to load jquery ui before jquery. I edited it now it works.

Comment: Thanks @Danmoreng. It would be very helpful with an example if you may.

Comment: do you mean increment / decrement? As is increase by one / decrease by one?

Comment: Thanks and yes. @ste-fu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go, I added comments in the code to explain what I did.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   var fixHelperModified = function(e, tr) {
         var $originals = tr.children();
         var $helper = tr.clone();
         $helper.children().each(function(index) {
            $(this).width($originals.eq(index).width())
         });
         return $helper;
      },
      // the updateIndex function works just fine without any parameters
      updateIndex = function() {
         $('td.index').each(function(i) {
            $(this).html(i + 1);
         });
      };
   $("#sort tbody").sortable({
      helper: fixHelperModified,
      stop: updateIndex
   }).disableSelection();
   $("#addNew").click(function() {
      $('#add').append("<tr class='rem'><td class='index'>1</td><td>1969</td><td><input name='foo'><button class='delete'>Delete</button></td></tr>");
      // just update indicies after adding a new element
      updateIndex();
   });
   $("body").on('click', '#add .delete', function() {
      $(this).closest(".rem").remove();
      // same after removing an element
      updateIndex();
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<table id="sort" class="grid">
    <button id='addNew'>Add new item</button>
    <thead>
        <tr><th class="index">No.</th><th>Year</th><th>Title</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="add">
        <tr class="rem"><td class="index">1</td><td>1969</td><td><input name="foo"><button class="delete">Delete</button></td></tr>
        <tr class="rem"><td class="index">2</td><td>1952</td><td><input name="bar"><button class="delete">Delete</button></td></tr>
        <tr class="rem"><td class="index">3</td><td>1963</td><td><input name="baz"><button class="delete">Delete</button></td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks. This is a very good lesson but there is an issue here. Please check adding 5/6 elements and deleting them all. They don't get deleted if `1969` is deleted once (the append). Any suggestion why this is happening?

Comment: The newly-added rows are missing the "rem" class, so `this.closest('.rem')` never matches them.  Could fix by changing that to `this.closest('tr')` or by including `class="rem"` when adding a new row

Comment: Thanks @DanielBeck. Just before you commented I noticed the problem. Thank you anyway for looking into it. It's solved now.  :)

Answer (score 1):

Danmoreng's solution will work fine in some cases but not if is necessary for the `$('td.index')` collection to be constrained with the context `ui.item.parent()` as in the question.

The cleanest solution I know of, that allows the context to be preserved, is slightly messy but not too bad.

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23516999/3478010), you can trigger the 'stop' method as follows ...

```
$("#add").sortable('option', 'stop')();
```

... but you need to pass a synthetic 'ui.item' (and that's why I say it's slightly messy).

```
$("#addNew").click(function(e) {
    // call the stop callback, passing synthetic (e, ui) parameters
    $("#add").sortable('option', 'stop')(e, {
        'item': $("<tr class='rem'><td class='index'>1</td><td>1969</td><td><input name='foo'> <button class='delete'>Delete</button></td></tr>").appendTo("#add")
    });
});

$("#add").on('click', '.delete', function(e) {
    var $tbody = $(this).closest('tbody');
    $(this).closest(".rem").remove();
    // call the stop callback, passing synthetic (e, ui) parameters
    $("#add").sortable('option', 'stop')(e, {
        'item': $tbody // the tbody element, dicovered *before* row was removed from it
    });
});
```

**[updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xv1foam2/3/)**

In the delete handler, passing `$tbody` is a convenience, which will not work under all circumstances. It works here because we know that the only thing `updateIndex()` will do with its `ui` argument is `$('td.index', ui.item.parent())`, and it doesn't matter whether `ui.item` is :

- a 'tr', in which case the parent is a tbody, or
- a tr's containing `tbody`, in which case the parent is a table element.

Either way, `$('td.index', ui.item.parent())` finds the required `td.index` elements.

Comment: Wow! That's an interesting and better way of solving this problem indeed. And a good lesson too. I really appreciate your effort on this suggestion. Thanks a lot.  :)