# When JQuery Sortable is triggered get list of ID's

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery Sortable to order my images. When I add or delete an image, I want sortable to be triggered and get a list of IDs so I can update the DB with the new order.

The below code works when I drag an image. It the database, but does not work when I trigger the update of the sortable.

```
 $(function () {
    $("#sortable").sortable({
        placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",            
        update: function (event, ui) {
            var ordering = $.map($("> li img", this), function (el) { return el.id }).join(",");                
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "address",
                data: { order: ordering },
                success: function (data) {
                 $(".selector").load("projectimages");

                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("error");
                }
            });
        }
    });
    $("#sortable").disableSelection();
});
```

When the sortable is triggered using this:

```
$("#sortable").sortable("option", "update")();
```

This piece of code

```
var ordering = $.map($("> li img", this), function (el) { return el.id }).join(",");
```

doesn't get the list of IDs like it does when the image is dragged.

I have tried using the [create](https://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-create) function but it doesn't work.

Comment: This question is nothing to do with triggering the sortable. The sortable is triggered. I want to get the list of id's like i do when the image is dragged @Rory McCrossan

Comment: It's still a duplicate. The issue is because you're not providing the scope of the element to the handler which should be referenced in `this`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23516999/519413) for the solution

Comment: I see what you mean about it being a duplicate. Due to your comments above i got it working.