# How to manually trigger 'update' in ui-sortable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm using an UI sortable with in each item a `delete` button. Here is the delete function:

```
$('.delete_item').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('.grid_3_b').remove();
    initSortable();
    $(".sortable").sortable('refresh').trigger('update');
});
```

The `div` get's removed as I want to, but there is no `update` data sent to PHP.. So my script won't save the order and deleted item..

Here is my `initSortable();` function:

```
function initSortable() {
    $( ".sortable" ).sortable({
        items: '.grid_3_b, .dropable',
        connectWith: ".sortable",
        placeholder: "placeholder",
        remove: function(event, ui) {
            if(!$('div', this).length) {
                $(this).next('.dropable').remove();
                $(this).remove();
            }
            initMenu();
        },
        receive: function(event, ui) {
            if( $(this).hasClass( "dropable" ) ) {
                if( $(this).hasClass( "gallery__item--active" ) ) {
                    $(this).before( "<div class=\"dropable gallery__item sortable\"></div>" );
                    $(this).after( "<div class=\"dropable gallery__item sortable\"></div>" );

                    initSortable();
                    $(".sortable").sortable('refresh').trigger('update');
                    initMenu();
                }
            }
        },
        update : function () {
            var neworder = new Array();
            $('.sortable').each(function() {
                var id  = $(this).attr("id");
                var pusharray = new Array();
                $('#' + id).children('div').each(function () {
                    var art = $(this).attr("data-art");
                    var pos = $(this).attr("data-pos");
                    pusharray.push( {data:{'art':art, 'pos':pos}} );
                });
                neworder.push({'id':id, 'articles':pusharray});
            });

            $.post("example.php",{'neworder': neworder},function(data){});
            initMenu();
        }
    }).disableSelection();
}

initSortable();
```

Also, the `remove` function normally deletes a column when it's empty, but doesn't work when deleted the latest item in the column.. Is this because the update trigger isn't called?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For manually triggering events in [jquery-ui sortable](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable), instead of specifying the handler in options object, you need to bind the event handler after sortable initialization.

For example the following will not work

```
$('ul').sortable({
  update: function () {
    console.log('update called');
  }
});
$('ul').trigger('sortupdate'); // doesn't work
```

Following works

```
$('ul').sortable();
$('ul').on('sortupdate',function(){
   console.log('update called');
});
$('ul').trigger('sortupdate'); // logs update called.
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eZcgR/1/)

Comment: You're awesome, thanks for taking the effort of answering this old question!

Comment: Hmm I have no idea. It was simply implemented like that by someone someday, or maybe proper callback is a missing feature